# How to convert a string to int using AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to query a number field from a table, and the value to query, is comming from a BuildRowsetFromString.  Whenever I try to query, I get this error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32. Input string was not in a correct format.

How can I convert the string BuildRowsetFromString generates, to a number?

Comment: Please can you provide an example of how you are using `BuildRowsetFromString()`?

Comment: Hard to help when there's no source code posted.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so AmpScript can covert string to int. You have to use [SSJS](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/server_side_javascript/) with a combination of AmpScript to convert string to int.

Also, use `JavaScript` [parseInt function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) in `SSJS` like below.

```
%%[
SET @FirstNumber = "10"
]%%

    <script runat=server>

    Platform.Load("core","1");

    var firstNumber = Variable.GetValue("@FirstNumber");
    var secondNumber = 10;
    var add = secondNumber+parseInt(firstNumber);
    Variable.SetValue("NewNumber",add);

    </script>

 %%=v(@NewNumber)=%%
```

**Output:** 20

Answer (score 0):

The returned result is of type `String`, try to parse by using `integer.valueof(s);` and check before if it's different from `NULL`.

Comment: I get this error:

The function call uses an unrecognized function name.
Function Name: integer.valueof